# Allow custom text for magic links

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

What about allowing things like

```
[Edit this question][edit]
[What's on topic?][help/on-topic]
[The proposal site][a51]
```

So they look like

> [Edit this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/296051/edit)
>   [What's on topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
>   [The proposal site](https://area51.stackexchange.com)

To reduce answers' and comments' (raw) length.

Oh, there's another thing. Can we have the text auto-generated so that we don't have to write

```
[Allow custom text for magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296051/allow-custom-text-for-magic-links)
```

but simply `[/q/296051]`? That'd be convenient (especially in comments)!

Comment: I like this idea. +1

Comment: Perhaps the format should be `[Edit this question](edit)` to be consistent with custom text hyperlinks.

Comment: There are 2 questions here, actually. **Before voting to close please find some references to Question 2.**

Comment: "There are two questions here" An SE post should only contain one question/feature request. Feel free to edit down to one or the other; the post can then be reopened if appropriate.